# Filter out or Hide all rows with blank aggregated column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm looking for a way to filter out or hide all rows that contain a blank value for the aggregated COLUMN values. For example, I need a way to mass hide (through sorting the column values across the entire pivot table) or filter out the orange highlighted rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi @geominded,, select Aggregate column, reach to Conditional Formatting,, pick option Highlight Cell Rule,, Text than Contents,,, in next Dialogue put Blank,,, in next list box select CUSTOM ,, and enter `;;;` & finish with Ok,,, if U want to automate all these U need VBA macro. ☺

Comment: This just formats the blanks though, correct? I need to actually remove the entire rows affected by any aggregated value column with a blank. Conditional Formatting doesn't work on the aggregated Values Avg of Price region group columns anyway :(

Comment: ,, using Conditional formatting to hide BLANK CELLS in any column and apply `;;;` is just a method, otherwise if you are looking for THE ROW to remove then PIVOT TABLE itself has facility,,, in DESIGN,,, Remove Blank.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this would be to add a formula column in your raw data.

I assumed that you had something like this in your raw data:

```
     A      B      C      D      E
1    Col1   Col2   Col3   Region Price
2    A      A      E      A      0.01
3    A      A      E      B      0.04
4    A      A      D      A      0.02
5    ...
```

In your example you have Region A and B. Add a column named "Check" in your raw data (in column F) and then below that (F2) a formula like this:

`=IF(D2="A",COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,D:D,"B"),COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,D:D,"A"))`

If Region shows "A" it will count the combination of column B and C for Region "B" and vice versa. If Region A or B does not have this combination it will show 0.

Example with formula:

```
     A      B      C      D      E      F
1    Col1   Col2   Col3   Region Price  Check
2    A      A      E      A      0.01   1
3    A      A      E      B      0.04   1
4    A      A      D      A      0.02   0
5    ...
```

In your pivot table you can now simply add the "Check" column to your filters area in the pivot and filter out all values that have 0 in it.

Comment: There is an added complexity that I'm using Groups on my Region A and B, where Region A is actually a group of 2 or 3 regions. I haven't figured out an easy way to create multiple columns, each to check for each combination of regions I'm comparing.